# ++ operator with String and IO String

Tags: string, haskell, io

```
explandDol :: String -> String -> [String] -> IO String
explandDol conclusion operators atoms =
    let (ys,zs) = splitAt (head (take 1 replacement)) conclusion in ys ++ getConclusion     operators atoms ++ (tail zs)
    where replacement = elemIndices '$' conclusion



getConclusion :: String -> [String] -> IO String
getConclusion operators atoms =
   runRVar (choice [atom1 ++ " " ++ [operator] ++ " " ++ atom2 | atom1 <- atoms, atom2 <-    atoms, operator <- operators,checkAtoms atom1 atom2]) StdRandom
```

Is there a good way to fix this? I am getting this error:

```
/home/joe/Documents/haskell/LAG/main/main.hs: line 73, column 69:
  Couldn't match expected type `IO String' with actual type `[Char]'
  In the expression: ys ++ getConclusion operators atoms ++ (tail zs)
  In the expression:
    let (ys, zs) = splitAt (head (take 1 replacement)) conclusion
    in ys ++ getConclusion operators atoms ++ (tail zs)
  In an equation for `explandDol':
      explandDol conclusion operators atoms
        = let (ys, zs) = splitAt (head (take 1 replacement)) conclusion
          in ys ++ getConclusion operators atoms ++ (tail zs)
        where
            replacement = elemIndices '$' conclusion
/home/joe/Documents/haskell/LAG/main/main.hs: line 73, column 75:
  Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `IO String'
  In the return type of a call of `getConclusion'
  In the first argument of `(++)', namely
    `getConclusion operators atoms'
  In the second argument of `(++)', namely
    `getConclusion operators atoms ++ (tail zs)'
/home/joe/Documents/haskell/LAG/main/main.hs: line 73, column 75:
  Warning: Redundant bracket
  Found:
    getConclusion operators atoms ++ (tail zs)
  Why not:
    getConclusion operators atoms ++ tail zs
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it answered you question.  If it is still unclear please feel free to ask clarifying questions in the comments or update you question with additional information and not it as such.

Answer (score 5):

Because value returned by `getConclusion` is `IO String` you cannot simply use it with functions operating on unwrapped values. Either first unwrap value using `x <- getConclusion operators atom` or if you want function composition use `fmap`.